# React: Communicate between sibling components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Hi I am new to React and wrote a small app with one form to get some practice. It consists of 4 components other than the `App.js` file. I am trying to have my `Checkbox.js` component communicate to my `SubmitButton.js` component whether or not it is checked so that the submit button will only be enabled if the user checks the box. I tried using props as you can see in the code below but I am probably doing this horribly wrong. Can anyone help me learn the correct way to do this? Not sure if it matters, but I am using the Material-UI library. Thanks.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import NavBar from './Components/NavBar'
import Form from './Components/InfoForm'
import SubmitButton from './Components/SubmitButton';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import Checkbox from './Components/Checkbox';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    checked: false,
});

const handleChange = name => event => {
  setState({ ...state, [name]: event.target.checked });
};

  return (
   <div>
     <Container maxWidth="md">
     <NavBar />
     <Form />
     <br />
     <Checkbox onChange={handleChange('checked')} checked={state.checked} /> 
     <SubmitButton isEnabled={state.checked} /> 
     </Container>     
   </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Checkbox.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';

function Checkboxes() {

  return (
    <div>
      <Checkbox
        name = 'checkbox'
        value="checked"
        inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'primary checkbox', }}
      /> By checking this box you agree to all terms and conditions specified above.
    </div>
  );
}

export default Checkboxes;
```

**SubmitButton.js**

```
    import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  button: {  margin: theme.spacing(1), },
  input: { display: 'none', },
}));

export default function ContainedButtons(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  if (props.isEnabled === 'true') {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.button}>
          Submit
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  } else 
  {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.button} disabled = 'true'>
          Submit
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Utilize props. Props are how you communicate state between components.

Comment: send checked state value as props to `<submit checked={state.checked}/>` in `checkbox.js` file

Answer (score 4):

The most basic and straightforward way is to lift shared functionality into the parent component, and pass the values and functions to the child components as props.

In your case, have some state in `App` that maintains if checkbox is checked, then pass the value and update function into the checkbox via props.  You can then toggle your button in `App` based on the value of checkbox indicator in the `App` state as well

In other words, you have got the right idea with using your indicator on the global window object, however, use the parent component instead of global variables.  When you find a need to really make things 'global' or accessible from various parts of your app, look at the likes of Redux for state management

e.g.

```
function App() {
    const [state, setState] = React.useState({
        checked: false,
  });
  return (
   <div>
     <Container maxWidth="md">
     <NavBar />
     <Form />
     <br />
     <Checkbox onChange={handleChange('checked')} checked={checked}/> 
     <SubmitButton isEnabled={checked}/> 
     </Container>     
   </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you Andy but would you mind providing a code example? That would be extremely helpful as I am not familiar with the concept ff logic being passed down via props from the parent level.

Comment: So you are already doing it in Checkboxes.js, where you are passing state.checked into the `Checkbox`, you just need to lift that state one level higher, into the App component, so that it is available to your submit button

Comment: i've added an example, its not a complete working solution, but should give you an idea about where to put the state and how to pass to children via props

Comment: Thank you so much Andy! Let me give it a shot and I'll let you know how it goes. I really appreciate the help...

Comment: I changed my code in the OP to reflect the changes you suggested but it is still not working. Can you take a look and let me know if you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You needed to pass your `checked` and `onChange` props on through your `Checkbox` component into the material `Checkbox`, also the conditional rendering of the button was slightly off, you just needed to toggle the disabled property based on the checked value.  Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my issue was the following code:

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import NavBar from './Components/NavBar'
import Form from './Components/InfoForm'
import SubmitButton from './Components/SubmitButton';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import Checkbox from './Components/Checkbox';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    checkbox: false,
});

const handleChange = event => {
  setState({ ...state, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked });
};

  return (
   <div>
     <Container maxWidth="md">
     <NavBar />
     <br />
     <Form />
     <Checkbox name="checkbox" onChange={handleChange} checked={state.checkbox} />
     <SubmitButton isEnabled={state.checkbox} /> 
     </Container>     
   </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Checkbox.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';

function Checkboxes(props) {
  const {onChange, checked} = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <Checkbox
        name = 'checkbox'
        value={checked}
        onChange={onChange} 
        inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'primary checkbox', }}
      /> By checking this box you agree to all terms and conditions specified above.
    </div>
  );
}

export default Checkboxes;
```

**SubmitButton.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  button: {  margin: theme.spacing(1), },
  input: { display: 'none', },
}));

export default function ContainedButtons(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();

    return (
      <div>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.button} disabled = {!props.isEnabled}>
          Submit
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
}
```